# asp.net page first load - show loading div before everything

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an asp page.
on first load of the page, the function Page_Load takes long time to finish (15 seconds) and I can't make it shorter.

I want to achieve this:

First thing the page shows, before everything, is a div with the word loading. Then after the Page_Load finishes I want to make this disappear.

How can this behavior be achieved?

Comment: I explained it here with using only javascript codes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43641469/3674349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a loading msg panel and a content panel.
This would allow the Page to first render a loading message and then invoke the request for the long request

```
void Page_Load(){
    var fromMsg = Request["loading"] == "1";
    if (!fromMsg) {
       LoadingPanel.Visible = true;
       ContentPanel.Visible = false
    } else {
       // Load Heavy Content Here
    }
}
```

Then in your Loading Panel just add some javascript to invoke a reload

```
<asp:Panel id="LoadingPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
    <script type='javascript'>
    window.setTimeout(function(){
       location.href = location.href += "&loading=1";
    }, 400);
    </script>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="ContentPanel" runat="server">
   ...
</asp:Panel>
```

If the loading message is simple you can accomplish the same thing in the CodeBehind with something simple like

```
void OnInit() 
{
    var fromMsg = Request["loading"] == "1";
    if (!fromMsg) {
       Response.Clear();
       Response.Write("<h2>Loading....</h2>");
       Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.setTimeout(function(){ location.href = 'ThisPage.aspx?loading=1'; }, 400);
       Response.End();
    }
}
```

If you needed to do this on a lot of pages you could create a Helper library to generate the MessageHtml and set the refresh JS with ScriptManager

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot!! this sounds like it would solve the problem but is it good practice? it sounds a bit crooked, isn't it?

Comment: The only way you can get an early "Loading Message" out to the browser is to either write a minimal amount and do a Response.Flush(), or render a small loading page and redirect to the heavy page.   With WebForms you may get side effects with the Response.Flush but you can definitely play with it and see what happens.

Comment: Works beautifully for me; appreciated.